# How to recursively call different methods for levels of a video game?

Tags: python

I attempting to design a simple choice based video game. Essentially what I want is a recursive loop that will continue to call the new levels based off the results of the previous. For example, in level 1 based off choice made it will either trigger level 2 or 3. This is the code I have so far:

```
class Levels:

    def __init__(self, Next = 1):
        self.Next = Next

    def Call(self):
        VarLevel = "Level" + "{}".format(self.Next)
        return ("{}".format(VarLevel))
```

This is the super class, it returns the VarLevel which equals Level1 to trigger the subclass Level1. This is the code I have for the levels, I've excluded the context of the game because I don't think it is necessary.

```
class Level1(Levels):

    def __init__(self,):
        # this just includes information about the level to show the user
        # (objective etc.)

    def Action(self):
        # this will include the content of the level. based off the choices
        # made I want it to return to the super with VarLevel as Level2 or 
        # Level3 and then to trigger the next level running and repeat 
        # throughout the program to run the game. For the purpose of testing 
        # the program the only content of Level1 is setting the return to 2 so 
        # that Level2 is called. I'm having trouble actually getting it to 
        # recognize my return and to trigger the next level. This is the 
        # actual method I want to do the calling with 

class LevelCall():

    def __init__(self, Levels = Levels):
        self.Levels = Levels
    def Calling(self):
        result = (Levels, "{}".format(Levels()))()
```

it gives me the error `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`. I have been doing a lot of different attempts to get it to work so I'm not certain that this is even the real problem with the code. Also of note I am decent in Java and am now transitioning to Python (this is my first attempt in Python other then basic tests to read/write etc.) Any help is greatly appreciated to help figure out how to format the game and I apologize in advance because I know this is a long question, I've never posted here before so if you need more info or clarification please feel free to ask.

Edit:
This is the full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 54, in <module>  
    Tester.Calling()  
  line 50, in Calling  
    result = (Levels, "{}".format(Levels()))()  
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Another Edit:
I think I am getting closer. I made the following changes

```
 class LevelCall():  
      def __init__(self, Levels = Levels):  
          self.Levels = Levels  
      def Calling(self):  
          Hold = Levels()  
          result = (getattr(Levels, "{}".format(Hold.Call()))())
```

It now gives the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  line 55, in <module>  
    Tester.Calling()  
line 51, in Calling  
    result = (getattr(Levels, "{}".format(Hold.Call()))())  
AttributeError: type object 'Levels' has no attribute 'Level1'
```

If I understand correctly it is now attempting to do what I want but isn't finding the class "Level1". Again all help is much appreciated.

Edit______________________
I would like to thank all who replied and attempted to help, I am truly grateful for the support. With the clarification you were able to help me with as well as a fresh start today and mapping it out in java first to make the transition easier I was able to solve my problem. Once again thank you all very much I will add the solution I found beneath this edit.

```
global Stop 
class Level1 :
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def Action(self):
        print ("1")
        global Stop
        Stop = input("Would you like to advance to the next level?")
        if (Stop == "yes"):
            # Lev = Level2()
            # return Lev.Action()
            return Level2
        if (Stop == "no"):
            return "stop"



class Level2:
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def Action(self):
        print("2")
        global Stop
        Stop = input("Would you like to advance to the next level?")
        if (Stop == "yes"):
            # Lev = Level3()
            # return Lev.Action()
            return Level3
        if (Stop == "no"):
            return "stop"

class Level3 :
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def Action(self):
        print ("3")
        global Stop
        Stop = input ("Next level??")
        if (Stop == "yes"):
            # Lev = Level4()
            # return Lev.Action()
            return Level4
        if (Stop == "no"):
            return "stop"

class Level4:
    def __init__(self):
        self

    def Action(self):
        print ("Complete")
        return "Done"

def Runner (Level):
    if (Level == "Done"):
        print ("Bye")
    else :
        if (Level != "stop"):
            Lev = Level()
            Next = Lev.Action()
            Runner(Next)

        if (Level == "stop"):
            print ("you chose to stop")




Runner(Level1)
```

Comment: I've proposed an edit to break those long commits into multiple lines, but your indentation also looks off (which I did not touch). Perhaps a copy/paste and/or formatting issue when entering code into SO? As for the error you're seeing, it'd be very useful to include a bit more detail. Full, or at least partial but complete line traceback, as it makes seeing the problem and giving you an answer. It's obvious where in the code the interpret believes you're trying to call a `tuple`.

Comment: agree with @OndrejK. Your indentations aren't correct. The problem seems in the last line of your code. `(Levels, "{}".format(Levels()))` is a tuple and you are trying to call the tuple `( ... )()` which couldn't be done.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will add more about the error in an edit

Comment: Recursion is probably the wrong approach to this problem anyway. `level=Level(); while True: level=level.next()` where the `next` method returns the next level is perhaps a better blueprint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this would differentiate from my current plan. It would still have the same problem would it not?

Comment: At this point, the question might be creeping into "too broad" category. But let's try working on it a bit more. `"{}".format(Hold.Call())` can be simplified to str(Hold.Call())` or in this case just `Hold.Call()` as it already returns a `str`. And int this case apparently `Level1`. `getattr(Levels, "Level1")` tries to access *class* (is this intentional?) attribute `Level1` of `Levels` which indeed is not there in your snippet. Hence the exception. One more hint for that line, drop the outer parenthesis and perhaps consider using a linter from the start, it can help write easier to read code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment to help and support me I was able to solve my problem and have added the solution in an edit if you would like to see it!

Answer (score 0):

`(a,b,c)` is tuple syntax. `(a,b,c)()` is a tuple being called like a function. That is what the error is referring to.

If we break the offending code down you can tell. What does it look like when you replace the call to `format` with an `arg` placeholder:
`(Levels, "{}".format(Levels()))()` becomes... 
`(Levels, arg)() # this is now clearly a tuple and you're treating it like a function.`

Not really sure how fixing that will help you with your levels problem tho.

If you want to call a function, do so like: `func(args)`.
If you want to define a tuple, do so like: `(a, b, ..., z)`.
But don't call a tuple like a function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, still have the same problem, but this does help my python understanding.